# PDF display in a window

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to pass a PDF path to be displayed in a window, however the path is not found, I am getting the following error:

`GET http://localhost:8081/home/MyPdf.pdf 404 (Not Found)`

The folder has a permission to be read, write and execute.

```
Ext.create(Ext.window.Window', {
     width : 800,
     height : 600,
     maximizable : true,    
     layout : 'fit',
     items : [ {
     html : '<object width="100%" height="100%" data=
     + /home/MyPdf.pdf + '"></object>'
    } ]
}).show();
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: check the path. this is not an extjs issue. see if you can get to the PDF in your browser.

Comment: are you using a linux machine and accessing the folder home in your root drive? ie: is the address to the file '/home/MyPdf.pdf' in your file system?

Comment: Yes, I can access `file:///home/MyPdf.pdf`

Comment: Do you know if I can show directly the generated PDF in browser without save it in my machine ??

Comment: what you mean without saving it on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are missing a: ' after "data=". This may be unlikely though, considering you are getting an error that includes the path.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to access the folder from within the folder in which the web page is held, like this:

```
//if your webpage is held in the directory: /opt/apache/htdocs/index.html, 
//then your path should look like this:
Ext.create(Ext.window.Window', {
     width : 800,
     height : 600,
     maximizable : true,    
     layout : 'fit',
     items : [ {
     html : '<object width="100%" height="100%" data="' + ../../../home/MyPdf.pdf + '"></object>'
    } ]
}).show();
```

try that and tell us what happens

Comment: I am getting the same error. Now I am trying to do this without save pdf in my local machine. I am using Jasper method that returns to me a array of bytes which is represents a pdf file, and I use it to render the pdf in browser directly, do you understand ?

Comment: try this path: './../../../home/MyPdf.pdf' <br/>
NOTE the single dot-slash at the beginning; './' and not '../'
the problem may occur in your .htaccess / folder access security of your server also, you may have to copy the file into your 'htdocs' folder or what ever your server root is called

Comment: alternatively you could use php's get_file_contents function: get_file_contents('/file/path/exam.ple')
would this work in your situation?